# How do I delete the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is there an undefined in the array? How do I delete the object?

```js
arr = [
  {id:1,name:'aaa'},
  {id:2,name:'bbb'},
  {id:3,name:'ccc'}
];

for(var item in arr){
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(item)){
    if(arr[item].id === 2){
      delete(arr[item]);
      continue;
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you are trying to do:-

```js
var arr = [
  {id:1,name:'aaa'},
  {id:2,name:'bbb'},
  {id:3,name:'ccc'}
];


arr = arr.filter(function(item){
  return item.id != 2;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `delete` don't arranges the indexes. From the documentation

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected.
>   This holds even if you delete the last element of the array

For removing you need to use **[Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** function, which removes by index. Find first the index using **[Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)** and then pass to the splice function.

```js
arr = [
  {id:1,name:'aaa'},
  {id:2,name:'bbb'},
  {id:3,name:'ccc'}
];

const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.id === 2);
arr.splice(index, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `arr` which is array of objects.The `delete` operator removes a given property from an object, in your case you need to shift the elements after removing the object

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'aaa'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbb'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ccc'
  }
];
// iterating the object
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  //checking if id === 2, if it is 2 using splice 
//method to remove element from that index, & shift by one element
  if (item.id === 2) {
    arr.splice(index, 1)
  }
})

console.log(arr);
```